# regular expression for DEA drug schedule variation

Tags: regex

Normally I'm pretty happy with my regex skills, but I'm having trouble with this one.  I need a pattern to verify a variation of the DEA drug schedule.  It looks like this:

```
22N 33N 4 5

1 2 3

22N-R 6
```

Basically there can be up to 6 'groups' separated by a space.  Each group can have 1 or 2 of it's number, followed by an optional N, followed by an optional -R.  There seem to be a few other restrictions (there is no 11 group) but that's not what is hanging me up.

I had this:

```
^(1(-R)?)?\s?(2(-R)?)?(2N(-R)?)?\s?(3|3-R)?(3N|3N-R)?\s?(4(-R)?)?\s?(5(-R)?)?\s?(6(-R)?)?$
```

But the issue is the \s? are optional.  So then this incorrectly passes:
22N33N45
If I make them required, then I can end up with leading or trailing spaces.

So, I think I need some kind of lookaround, only have a space if it's surround by a 'group'?

And here is the catch, I am required to do this with 1 regex.  I can't split on spaces and then regex the parts, that would be too easy!  Any input would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: Insead of `(1(-R)?)?\s?` you could use `(1(-R)?(\s|$))?`, making the space (or end of string) a required part of the optional 1-group. You'll need to apply that to all other groups too.

Comment: The N can occur only when there 2 digits in the number ?

Comment: @Gawil Good catch, the N can only show up if there are two of the same numbers.  Like 22N or 33N.  2N is invalid.

Comment: @SebastianProske I like the idea behind: (1(-R)?(\s|$))?  but I need it to require a \s IF there are multiple groups.  I can't have 2233 pass.  So somehow the \s needs to conditionally required?

Comment: Well you would apply the same to the 2-group, like `((2|22N?)(-R)?(\s|$))?` - now it either has to end with this group, or there is a space required between 2 and 3-group or whatever follows. Something like https://regex101.com/r/XnFp6V/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sebastian-proske put me on the right track, very clever sir!  Making the existing regex either end the line, or have a space did the trick:

^((1(-R)?)(\s|$))?((2|22)N?(-R)?(\s|$))?((3|33)N?(-R)?(\s|$))?((4(-R)?)(\s|$))?((5(-R)?)?(\s|$))?(6(-R)?)?$

Thanks to all for the quick help.

Comment: Careful, this would match strings like 2-R2N-R. I don't know if this is intended or not...

Comment: Now this also matches 3N ;)

Comment: 3N (I'm told) is OK.  I guess in fact simply 1 is valid.  And even _empty_ is valid (ha!).  Thanks again for the awesome help, great catches.

Comment: Oh ok ! It's just that you said earlier that 2N was invalid. Anyway I can't see  anything else that could cause problems, so good job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this regex :
`^(?:1(?:-R)?\s|$)?(?:(?:22N|2)(?:-R)?\s|$)?(?:(?:33N|3)(?:-R)?\s|$)?(?:4(?:-R)?\s|$)?(?:5(?:-R)?\s|$)?(?:6(?:-R)?$)?`
This is very long and very repetitive, but if understood correctly, the numbers have to be in increasing order, so I don't see any other solution...

**Edits :**
44N, 55N and 66N seem impossible, according to your initial regex, so I removed them.
Prevented string ending with a space from matching
Replaced the negative lookaheads by a simple "|"

Answer (score -1):

This works for your examples and your explanation, as best I can understand it:

```
^((1|2|3|4|5|6|11N?|22N?|33N?|44N?|55N?|66N?)(-R)?)(\s(1|2|3|4|5|6|11N?|22N?|33N?|44N?|55N?|66N?)(-R)?){0,5}$
```

That is: start with your one number, or 2 followed by optional N, followed by optional -R; then repeat that pattern (with a required space in front) up to 5 times.